# How to remove lines [DEBUG] pip.vcs: Registered VCS backend: *** from log file

Tags: python, django, git, logging

Logger repeat these lines again and again in my log file. What is meaning of these line and how remove them ?

```
2015-12-24 15:40:02,025 [DEBUG] pip.vcs: Registered VCS backend: hg
2015-12-24 15:40:02,048 [DEBUG] pip.vcs: Registered VCS backend: svn
2015-12-24 15:40:02,049 [DEBUG] pip.vcs: Registered VCS backend: bzr
2015-12-24 15:45:01,532 [DEBUG] pip.vcs: Registered VCS backend: git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comes from [`pip/vcs/__init__.py#L53-L59`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/034232f0e0419bbc9c3a8e63413a7b4bda5263de/pip/vcs/__init__.py#L53-L59)

```
def register(self, cls):
    if not hasattr(cls, 'name'):
        logger.warning('Cannot register VCS %s', cls.__name__)
        return
    if cls.name not in self._registry:
        self._registry[cls.name] = cls
        logger.debug('Registered VCS backend: %s', cls.name)
```

In order to not see that log, you would need to comment out that line, or to set a different log level (not debug).

Comment: Thanks for ans. but unable to find this file :( .

Comment: OS  ubuntu,  python 2.7

Comment: @GrvTyagi Where did you search? `find /usr -name "*init*.py" 2>/dev/nul | grep vcs`

Comment: locate pip/vcs/__init__.py       help  in this ...

vim /home/ubuntu/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/__init__.py 
 
and comment line no. 53 in ubuntu